# Change in Angular2 RC5 ExceptionHandler?

Tags: angular, exceptionhandler

I'm migrating my Angular2 code to RC5 and can't figure out how to wire up my exception handling.  In the RC4, it was part of the bootstrapping process in Main.ts:

```
bootstrap(MyApp, [{provide: ExceptionHandler, useClass: GlobalExceptionHandler}])
```

But now that we have an app.module.ts, I'm not sure how to include the reference to ExceptionHandler and point it at GlobalErrorHandler.  My new app.module.ts is below:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule  } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { AppComponent }   from "./app.component";
import { ExceptionHandler } from "@angular/core";
import { GlobalErrorHandler } from "./shared/utils/global-error-handler";
import { ExceptionApiService } from "./shared/utils/exception-api-service";
import { HomeComponent }   from "./home/home.component";
import { ContentManagementComponent } from "./contentManagement/content-management.component";
import { GetContentComponent } from "./getContent/get-content.component";
import { AddContentComponent } from "./addContent/add-content.component";
import { ErrorComponent } from "./errorPage/error.component";
import { appRoutingProviders, APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from "./app.routes";
import { APP_PROVIDERS } from "./app.providers";

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent, HomeComponent,     ContentManagementComponent, GetContentComponent, AddContentComponent, ErrorComponent ],
    providers:    [ appRoutingProviders, APP_PROVIDERS, GlobalErrorHandler, ExceptionApiService ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

// How to bootstrap ExceptionHandler and point at GlobalErrorHandler??

export class AppModule {}
```

Any ideas?  Not a whole lot of documentation out there related to ExceptionHandling...especially for RC5 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to other providers, you need to inject it into your module.

```js
@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent, HomeComponent,     ContentManagementComponent, GetContentComponent, AddContentComponent, ErrorComponent ],
    providers:    [ appRoutingProviders, APP_PROVIDERS, {provide: ExceptionHandler, useClass: GlobalExceptionHandler}, ExceptionApiService ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```