# angular 2 - show error message for any exception

Tags: angular, error-handling

I'm trying to do the following in Angular 2 (typescript): For each error (especially errors from the backend server) - present the error to the user (in the UI) - in the main component (mainly since I do't want to write same code in each component).

Is it a simple way to do it? I guess what I need is a way to set an "error" member in the main component? How do I do it if I override ExceptionHandler?

thanx,
Pavel.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882969/change-in-angular2-rc5-exceptionhandler and https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ExceptionHandler-class.html You should be aware that not catching exceptions locally can leave your component in an undefined state. You might need to invoke change detection afterwards explicitely. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37793276/angular-2-custom-exceptionhandler-change-detection-lag/37793791#37793791

Comment: Hi Günter, My question is how do I make the ExceptionHandler change some state in the main app component (to present an error message in the UI)?

Comment: You can use a shared service where you update the state from the exception handler or emit events using observables and a component that updates the DOM (show error information) depending on the info from that service.

Comment: Hi Günter, If I understand correctly, you suggest: In ExceptionHandler - call MyService.setErrorState(true), then in main component add ngif calling MyService.getErrorState(). But who will call MyService.setErrorState(false) when moving to next page?

Comment: That depends on your requirements. Perhaps you want to wait until the user clicks "dismiss" or just a timeout so the message disappears after 10 seconds, ...

Comment: thanx Günter. I eventually decided to do an other thing (handle the error on component level), and there I have no problem - I can clear it in onInit().

Answer (score 18):

1. Create NotificationService in shared directory

   ```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { Message } from 'primeng/primeng';

   @Injectable()
   export class NotificationService {
       message: Message[];

       constructor() {
           this.message = [];
       }

       success(detail: string, summary?: string): void {
           this.message.push({
               severity: 'success', summary: summary, detail: detail
           });
       }

       info(detail: string, summary?: string): void {
           this.message.push({
               severity: 'info', summary: summary, detail: detail
           });
       }

       warning(detail: string, summary?: string): void {
           this.message.push({
               severity: 'warn', summary: summary, detail: detail
           });
       }

       error(detail: string, summary?: string): void {
           this.message.push({
               severity: 'error', summary: summary, detail: detail
           });
       }
   }
   ```
2. create a custom ExceptionHandler (ErrorHandler in RC 6) in shared directory

   ```
   import { ErrorHandler, Inject } from '@angular/core';
   import { NotificationService } from './notification.service';


   export class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

       constructor(@Inject(NotificationService) private notificationService: NotificationService) {
       }

       handleError(error: any): void {
           this.showErrorInConsole(error);
           setTimeout(() => 
               this.notificationService.error(error.json().Message), 1);
       }

       private showErrorInConsole(error: any) :void {
           if (console && console.group && console.error) {
               console.group("Error Log");
               console.error(error);
               console.error(error.message);
               console.error(error.stack);
               console.groupEnd();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. update AppModule for overriding default error handler

   ```
   import { GrowlModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
   ...
   import { NotificationService } from './shared/notification.service';
   import { CustomErrorHandler } from './shared/custom-error-handler';

   @NgModule({
       imports: [
           ...,
           GrowlModule // prime ng notification
       ],
       declarations: [
           ...
       ],
       providers: [
           ...,
           NotificationService, // added
           { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: CustomErrorHandler } // overrride default error handler
       ],
       bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   export class AppModule { }
   ```
4. finally in AppComponent:

   ```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { Message } from 'primeng/primeng';
   import { NotificationService } from './shared/notification.service';


   @Component({
       selector: 'my-app',
       template: `
           <p-growl [value]="getMessages()"></p-growl>
       `
   })
   export class AppComponent{
       constructor(private notification: NotificationService) {
       }

       getMessages(): Message[] {
           return this.notification.message;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I had to use the following in my template: <p-growl [(value)]="this.notificationService.messages"></p-growl> in order to get the binding to work correctly, notificationService being made a public member of the component.

Comment: Note that `GrowlModule` has now been deprecated. Use Toast instead. https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/8328

Comment: Also worth using PrimeNG `MessageService` . Example: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/91114a019cda073634f093ffd16511d375825f79/src/app/showcase/components/toast/toastdemo.ts